# How to uiview into a CPtemplate

Tags: swift, wkwebview, carplay

I'm trying to replace the map on the carplay app of this [sample project](https://github.com/hansemannn/iOS12-CarPlay-Example) by a [carplay webview](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/carplay/system-elements/web-views/).

---

Here the function that returns the **root template**, to be show on **CarPlay** :

The problem, is that the setRootTemplate function needs a CPTemplate, and I don't know how to create a template and put a uiview on that ?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didConnectCarInterfaceController interfaceController: CPInterfaceController, to window: CPWindow) {
   
        let webViewClass : AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString("UIWebView")!
        let webViewObject : NSObject.Type = webViewClass as! NSObject.Type
        let webview: AnyObject = webViewObject.init()
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        webview.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
        let uiview = webview as! UIView

        // tried that too...  let myCPTemplateHere = webview as! CPTemplate

        // Here
       
        interfaceController.setRootTemplate(myCPTemplateHere, animated: true)
}
```

I tried with WKWebView too

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
webView.uiDelegate = self
let myURL = URL(string:"https://www.apple.com")
let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
webView.load(myRequest)
```

## Thanks a lot !

**PS: This app is for my own usage, I will not send it to the app store.**

Comment: You cannot use a webview (or any view for that matter) in CarPlay. Apple is extremely restrictive with which UI is possible in a car and allowing arbitrary web content would open doors to showing games, videos and all kinds of other distractions from traffic

Comment: Igor Magès, Can you solved the problem ? Because of I want to make an app like you